# How do I attach debugger to an app running on the Apple Watch?

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I want to debug my Apple Watch app in the same way as when it is being run on the simulator. When running on the simulator, Debug > Attach To Process will show the apple watch app, but this does not show up when running the app on a real Apple Watch. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running, make sure your apple watch application and device are selected on the dropdown menu. This way it should attach automatically when running.

[image: Dropdown menu screenshot]